# Dynamically update a TextField without using AsyncTask

Tags: android

I've got a short question. How can I update a TextField without using an AsyncTask? In my Activity class I've got a function like this:

```
private void CheckBlueToothState(){

      if (bluetoothAdapter == null){
            status.setText("Bluetooth NOT support.");
        }else{
            if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
                    status.setText("Bluetooth is currently in device discovery process.");
                }else{
                    status.setText("Bluetooth is Enabled");
                    search.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }else{
                status.setText("Bluetooth is NOT Enabled");
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }
    }
```

Which checks if  device got Bluetooth, is it enabled or disabled, you hopefully got the picture. So over to my question once again. How can I dynamically change the textfield `status` if I turn of the bluetooth, and vice versa?

Comment: Try using a Handler for updating the texts in the UI thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Register [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) with intent action `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED` and move your text updating code into `onReceive` method.

Example code could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693755/detecting-state-changes-made-to-the-bluetoothadapter).