# How to use extras from the intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

i am learning how to use Bluetooth with android, and I registered a `BroadCastReceiver` for `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED`.
in the docs, it say

> Broadcast Action: The state of the local Bluetooth adapter has been changed.
>      For example, Bluetooth has been turned on or off.
>      Always contains the extra fields EXTRA_STATE and EXTRA_PREVIOUS_STATE
>      containing the new and old states respectively.

now, how can i use  EXTRA_STATE and EXTRA_PREVIOUS_STATE?

Comment: [Example implicit intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ExampleSend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9694138/3309562):

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
        final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                                             BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
        switch (state) {
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
            //Bluetooth off
            break;
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
            //Turning Bluetooth off...
            break;
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
            //Bluetooth on
            break;
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
            //Turning Bluetooth on...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

};

Comment: your answer is helpful, but in my case, i registered for many actions almost 7 actions, do u think it is better to use on broad cast receiver for all or on a broad cast receiver for each action i wish to listen to?

Comment: In most cases one BroadcastReceiver is what you want. If this cleared up your question please make sure to mark this as the answer.