# Android - Service with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, background, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

My app have a background service that detect objects via bluetooth, and I want to show a dialog in the current activity (Logic to detect app in foreground or background is done) when a BT object is detected.
I read about BroadcastReceiver class, but I don't know how can send data from my service to a broadcast for my current activity to show a Dialog in the Activity.

If you know another solution that will be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [Android service broadcastreceiver example](http://www.truiton.com/2014/09/android-service-broadcastreceiver-example/) to achieve your goal.

As alternatives you need to provide your `Service` class a callback to the MainActivity. You can use [Bound services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you would not send data from the service to your class.
You would start the class in your current activity with a listener waiting for response from your service. If a positive response is given the dialog is shown

BroadcastReceiver class is used within the service and not within your current activity class.

Answer (score 0):

when your service detects device,you should send a broadcast receiver from the service,like this:

```
 final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
 sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And in your activity register this receiver with the action.

you can refer this,it's a [BLE sample](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt/BluetoothLeService.html#l67) by google:

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do to receive such broadcasts is to look for the Bluetooth State Changed, as is [documented here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html). Your code will look something like this ([Copied from this question, with some modification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9694138/544198))

```
public class BluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            //See if new bluetooth objects detected
        }
    }
};
```

Next you need to add your receiver to your manifest. Something like this is needed:

```
<receiver android:name=".BlutoothReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>" />
</receiver>
```

Beyond this, read the documentation listed above.