# how to wait till bluetooth turn on in android

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I need to turn on Bluetooth in an android device programmatically and wait till it on to proceed to next line of code.

My code is as below

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                ctx.startActivity(enableBtIntent);
}
```

When doing like this, the code continue to execute from next line without waiting for bluetooth completely on. Is there any way to solve this? Can I add a look to check if bluetooth is on?

Comment: You could try to `startActivityForResult`, but I don't know what the result code would be if an error did occur for some strange reason

Comment: Please write your full class so that we can answer it properly.

Comment: I would register a BroadcastReceiver to listen for state changes on the bluetooth adapter. This answer should solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693755/detecting-state-changes-made-to-the-bluetoothadapter

Comment: use this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_bluetooth.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Thanks @Neil I solved my problem using BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @Neil You should probably add Your comment as an answer, or Vineesh You should post how You resolved Your problem. Just so it is easier to find solution and see that the question is answered.

Comment: @morynicz good idea.

Comment: @Vineesh please accept my answer as the solution to your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for state changes on the BluetoothAdapter.

First create a `BroadcastReceiver` that will listen for state changes

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int bluetoothState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                                                BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            switch (bluetoothState) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                //Bluethooth is on, now you can perform your tasks
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then **register** the `BroadcastReceiver` with your `Activity` when it is created so that it can start receiving events.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Set a filter to only receive bluetooth state changed events.
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}
```

Remember to **unregister** the listener when the `Activity` is destroyed.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `startActivityForResult()` and check for whether *resultCode* is **RESULT_OK** in `onActivityResult()` with bluetooth permission in your Manifest file like..

```
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableIntent, 0);
}
```

onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        // bluetooth enabled                      
    }else{
        // show error
    }       
}
```

[ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)

Comment: @user3182143 what issue ?

Comment: Please add the comments in above link.The Questioner tell you the problem.

Comment: @user3182143 still didnt get that

Comment: This doesn't work for me, code still just executes, no waiting.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code
Permissions on your menifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

and code

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
     Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
     startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent , 0);
  } else
  {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Already on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Turned on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you place the Toasting inside of an onActivityResult method? What you have is no different than simply using startActivity

Comment: see updaetd answer

Answer (score 0):

startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //do your things
}
```