# Android Enable/ Disable Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a code, in my app, where a button press turn on bluetooth on and off.

I want to change the background of this button to green and red, when the bluetooth is either on or off. I did google answers for it and there is a stackoverflow post similar to it and the way he mentioned is not working. I  registered a receiver and have a switch case as usual, where I mentioned this button color change and it s not working.

Infact the log.d in the receivers are not even being shown up in the terminal of android studio.

THE CODE IS NOT ABOUT HOW TO IMPLETMENT THE COLOR, BUT ACCESSING THE STATE CHANGE OF BLUETOOTH FROM BROADCAST RECEIVER

```
   public void enableDisableBT(){
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: Does not have BT capabilities");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Bluetooth Capability", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: enabling BT");
            //btnONOFF.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); // Since bluetooth is NOT enabled, it enables bluetotoh and sets background color to green
            Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBTIntent);

            IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
        }
        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: disabling BT");
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            btnONOFF.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);// Since bluetooth is  enabled, it disables bluetotoh and sets background color to green
            incomingMessages.setText("Incoming Messages");
            IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
        }

    }

 private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // when discovery finds a device
            if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED)){
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch (state){
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: STATE OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        //Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE ON");
                        btnONOFF.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING ON");
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: As simple as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806536/how-to-enable-disable-bluetooth-programmatically-in-android

Comment: @leonz I am programmatically enabling/ disabling bluetooth. I just want to control the background color of the button based on bluetooth status.

Comment: Can you please post your full  java codes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a BroadcastReceiver in your manifest to listen to Bluetooth state.  This article sums it up well: https://droidhat.com/broadcast-receiver-using-change-in-bluetooth-status

1)

```
/**
 * A receiver that listens to Bluetooth getting turned on.
 */
 public class BluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    int state;
    switch (action) {
        case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED:
            state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1);
            if (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
                // change my button color
            }
     }
   } 
 }
```

2)

```
<receiver          
  android:name="com.myapp.BluetoothReceiver"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:exported="true">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
                    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```