# Exit Android application if user denies to turn Bluetooth on

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, android-bluetooth

I have a Kotlin application, which checks whether Bluetooth adapter is turned on or turned off. If the Bluetooth adapter is turned off, the application requests user to allow Bluetooth on the device.

**The problem is:** when user pushes *Allow* button, `onActivityResult` callback prints that Bluetooth is allowed to be used. But if user pushes *Deny* button, `onActivityResult` callback prints nothing. It looks like `onActivityCallback` can react only either user allows Bluetooth or error occurs.

**I need to implement the following feature:** if user denies Bluetooth request (press *Deny* button), the application needs to exit. Is there any way to implement it?

Here is how I create Bluetooth adapter instance and request user to allow Bluetooth usage:

```
// Create bluetooth adapter instance
    val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        bluetoothManager.adapter
    }

// Check if bluetooth is turned on, otherwise request user to turn it on
    var bluetooth_requested = false
    while (bluetoothAdapter != null && bluetoothAdapter!!.isDisabled) {
        if (!bluetooth_requested) {
            SetupBLE(bluetoothAdapter)
            bluetooth_requested = true
        }
    }
```

The function requests user to allow Bluetooth:

```
fun MainActivity.SetupBLE(bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter?) {
    val blueToothIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
    ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult( this, blueToothIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT, null )
}
```

Here is how I overrided `onActivityResult` fuction in `MainActivity`

```
// Overrided onActivityResult callback
    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d("onActivityResult", "The result is Allow!!!")
            } else {
                Log.d("onActivityResult", "The result is Deny!!!")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693755/detecting-state-changes-made-to-the-bluetoothadapter

Answer (score 3):

just call `finish()` inside else