# How to know if my App is connected to a device using BLE in Flutter?.. when app is the beacon

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

So my android app is behaving as a `beacon`, means, it will be `advertising` and other `BLE devices` will be connecting to it. Well, this is how our project is working so please don't raise questions on this as why am i using my app as a beacon and not as a scanner. Anyways, It behaves as a beacon and starts advertising and now I want to know that if a device connected to it. I cant find a way how to do this.

Of course, I am using this flutter package. `beacon_broadcast 0.3.0`

This is my **code**.

```js
  void startAdvertising() {
    BeaconBroadcast beaconBroadcast = BeaconBroadcast();
    beaconBroadcast
        .setUUID(advertisingUUID)
        .setMajorId(1)
        .setMinorId(100)
        .start();
  }
```

Comment: Did you find a way to check the connected device to a beacon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Flutter is just a UI toolkit and has no support for other system APIs such as Bluetooth.

You should therefore look what the official Android APIs offer in the first place. Usually when using [BluetoothLeAdvertiser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser) for advertising, one often also adds an instance of [BluetoothGattServer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer) in order to handle connections. If you have created a BluetoothGattServer using [openGattServer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager#openGattServer(android.content.Context,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattServerCallback)), you will get a [onConnectionStateChange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServerCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice,%20int,%20int)) callback whenever a device connects or disconnects. So that answers your question how an Android app can get notified when a device connects. You probably also want to use the same API to add a GATT service so that the other device can communicate with your app. Other alternatives is to use the GATT client API if it's the other device that has a GATT server, or you might want to use the L2CAP CoC API.

Note that if Bluetooth is turned off/disabled/restarted, your BluetoothGattServer object will automatically die and you need to recreate it. To get notified when this happens, use a state change intent receiver for `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED` as explained in this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/9694138/556495 to recreate your BluetoothGattServer (and advertiser) when state is changed to `STATE_ON`.

Now, since you want to use Flutter but Flutter uses Dart, you cannot directly consume the Android APIs. Instead you need to write a bridge/plugin, to bridge your Dart code and Java code. See https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels for a tutorial how to do this. If you're lucky, someone else might have already created such a package that does exactly what you want. Unfortunately, the beacon_broadcast package you found, only implements BluetoothLeAdvertiser and not BluetoothGattServer, as can be seen by the source code here: https://github.com/pszklarska/beacon_broadcast/tree/master/android/src/main/kotlin/pl/pszklarska/beaconbroadcast.

Comment: BPerfectly answers my question! Actually i have implented `BluetoothLeAdvertiser` and `BluetoothGattServer` in android, and now i was supposed to do the same in flutter. I found this package `beacon_broadcast` which lets me advertise, so i thought maybe it would also give me other information like connection state and other stuffs. But apparently from your answer, all i can do is `advertise`.