# How do apps like BUMBLE know as soon as the user disables LOCATION?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-lifecycle

There are many apps which require location permission to operate. For example, [BUMBLE](https://bumble.com/). While using the app, if I disable location from the notification bar, it immediately knows, and degrades the functionality, while preserving the state of the app. When I turn it back on, it resumes full functionality. How to implement the same thing in my Android app? Bluetooth being enabled is crucial to the functioning of my app.

EDIT:
I'm mainly interested in implementing a similar system for Bluetooth. My app involves many activities like scanning for ble devices, maintaining ble connections and communication, etc, which makes the app crash when the user turns off bluetooth from the notification bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FusedLocationProviderClient` to request location updates. One of the callback functions tells you the location availability. See [Request Location Updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates).

Note that you'll need to call the `requestLocationUpdates` that takes a `LocationCallback` to override the `onLocationAvailability` function.

For Bluetooth, you need to listen for a system broadcast. See [Detecting state changes made to the BluetoothAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693755/detecting-state-changes-made-to-the-bluetoothadapter)

I'm not positive this still works; it's a rather old answer (I remember using that approach a long while back) but it might not work with more recent bluetooth

Comment: How do I identify the MOMENT Bluetooth is turned off? Is there some background process I have to keep running?

Comment: Sorry - missed the bluetooth part - edited answer